# escape special char in ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

Need help with escaping special characters for lineinfile

I'm trying to do the following to simply change the bash prompt

```
- name: Editing bashrc to change bash prompt
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/bashrc
    regexp:  "export PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w #\[\033[00m\]'"
    line:  "export PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w #\[\033[00m\]'"
```

but as you can see, the regexp: value is full of special characters that I need to escape. Is there a simple way to escape the entire line? Or maybe there's another way I should be doing this?

i did try to do the following:
1 : add the text in a variable for re-use

```
- hosts: ssh
  vars:
    export: "export PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w #\[\033[00m\]'"
- name: Editing bashrc to change bash prompt
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/bashrc
    line: "{{ export }}"
```

and even with !unsafe for raw_strings

2. To escape special characters within a regex, use the “regex_escape” filter:

{{ '^f.*o(.*)$' | regex_escape() }}

maybe my syntax is not goot but i keep having an issue:

```
The offending line appears to be:

  vars:
    export: "export PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w #\[\033[00m\]'"
                         ^ here
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non exhaustive answer but these are the most straightforward examples IMO.

Option 1: escape the backslashes inside the double quotes

```yaml
export: "export PS1='\\[\\033[01;31m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[01;34m\\] \\w #\\[\\033[00m\\]'"
```

Option 2: get rid off the outer quotes using a scalar block

```yaml
export: |-
  export PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w #\[\033[00m\]'
```

You can have a look at e.g. [learn yaml in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) to get an overview of the different solutions to declare a string in yaml and the different types of escapes they support.

Comment: option 2 is actually the best of the string management by Ansible. Thanks!